# Retrieve URL from XML

Tags: xml, parsing, url, xpath

I have the following XML -

```
<title type="text/html">First part of string</title>
<content type="text/html"><p>And Second part of string</p> </content>
<link rel="alternate" type="text/html" href="http://www.FooBar.com"/>
```

And have used the following script in `XPath` -

```
use XML::XPath;
use XML::XPath::XMLParser;

my $file = 'MY.xml';
my $xp = XML::XPath->new(filename=>$file);

my $body = $xp->findvalue('entry/activity:object/content');
print "$body\n";
my $title = $xp->findvalue('entry/activity:object/title');
print "$title\n";
```

Which returns -

```
First part of string And Second part of string
```

I also need it to output the -

```
http://www.FooBar.com
```

I tried adding -

```
my $URL = $xp->findvalue('entry/activity:object/link');
print "$URL\n";
```

But this did not output anything.

How can I edit my script to include the URL string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The href value is an attribute of the link element, so use:

```
<path>/link/@href
```

Answer (score 2):

The URL is in the `href` attribute, not in the text content of the `link` element (it doesn't have any), so you need

```
entry/activity:object/link/@href
```